# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!e^{- \pi (x+iy)^2}\,dx = 1$ for all $y$.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

Can anyone provide a proof of why $\int _{-\infty} ^ {\infty} e^{-\pi (x+iy)^2} dx$ equals 1, for all y ? $x$ and $y$ are real numbers.

EDIT: We already know this for y=0.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you already know this for $y=0$?

Comment: @75064 Of height $y$.

Answer (score 2):

1. By the Cauchy integral theorem,  $\int_{\partial R}f(z)\,dz=0$ where $R$ is the rectangle with vertices $\pm A$, $\pm A+iy$, and $A$ can be any positive number.
2. For $z$ lying on either vertical side of $R$ we have $\mathrm{Re}\,(z^2)\ge A^2-y^2$. (Why?)
3. When $A\ge 2|y|$, the function $e^{-\pi z^2}$ does not exceed $e^{- \pi A^2/2}$ on either vertical side of $R$. (Why?)
4. The contribution of the vertical sides of $R$ to the integral  $\int_{\partial R}f(z)\,dz$ tends to zero as $A\to\infty$. (Why?)
5. $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A e^{-\pi (x+iy)^2}\,dx = \lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^A e^{-\pi x^2}\,dx$.

I assumed you already know that the integral converges. If this is not known, then either replace endpoints $\pm A$ with $A,B$ where $A<0<B$, or argue convergence separately, using the comparison test.